# How to align my social media button to the top right

Tags: php, css

I want to align the DISPLAY_ULTIMATE_PLUS social media buttons on the upper right corner. I tried several alignments methods but it won't seem to work. Here is the code.

```
<?php
/**
* The template for displaying the header
*
* Displays all of the head element and everything up until the 
"site-        content" div.
*
* @package WordPress
* @subpackage Twenty_Sixteen
* @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
*/

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js">
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<?php if ( is_singular() && pings_open( get_queried_object() ) ) : ?>
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<?php echo DISPLAY_ULTIMATE_PLUS(); ?>
<?php echo do_shortcode("[huge_it_slider id='2']"); ?>
<div class='mailmunch-forms-widget-295732'></div>
```

Comment: Could you please provide the actual HTML markup of your DISPLAY_ULTIMATE_PLUS social media buttons.

Comment: It's a plugin. They just provided me with this code and I put it on my header.php

Comment: <?php echo DISPLAY_ULTIMATE_PLUS(); ?>

Answer (score 0):

Apply :

```
position: absolute;

top: 0;
right: 0;
```

on the media button, and `position: relative;` on a parent `<div>` relatively to which it will be aligned.

**or**

Apply:

```
position: fixed;

top: 0;
right: 0;
```

on the media button.

---

You can style your html inline, using `style=""`.

Comment: Where exactly do I do that? I'm using wordpress. In what file do I edit that code?

Comment: <div
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     right: 0;
     <?php echo DISPLAY_ULTIMATE_PLUS(); ?>
     </div>

Comment: @EduardCastellano It is made on the theme you're using, you can find themes folder at: `/wp-content/themes/<your_theme_name>`.

Inside of that folder there should be `.css` ot `.scss` files that you can edit to style your theme.